# Не работает обработчик событий js

Tags: javascript

Помогите понять в чём проблема. Задаю скрипт внизу страницы, один обработчик работает, второй отказывается запускаться и даже не реагирует.

```
let deleteTODO = document.querySelector('.delete');

deleteTODO.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(1);
})
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что он не работает?

Comment: Добавьте еще код из предыдущим обработчиком событий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы щелкаете не на тот `'.delete'`, которому добавляете обработчик события.

Comment: <button class="add">Добавить</button>
<button class="delete">Удалить</button> Класс как видите тоже совпадает, как можно жмякнуть не на ту кнопочку?)

Comment: @maks-maks157 Это что?

Comment: Код из html, само собой что подключаю по классу

Comment: @maks-maks157 Вы создаете элементы `'.delete'` динамически - не хотите показать как, у них нет никаких обработчиков событий.

Comment: Стоп стоп стоп. Создал в файле html, я может не очень понимаю JS но одна из кнопочек работает таким образом, почему бы второй не начать работать?

Comment: @maks-maks157 "почему бы второй не начать работать" - потому что Вы не хотите как следует задать вопрос. Создайте работающий пример - кнопка "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса.

Comment: Igor - добавил, в HTML это код из файла .html. В JavaScript код файла .js. Через JavaScript элементов не создавал если вы про это, всё подключение чисто по классам. Посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @maks-maks157 Создайте работающий пример (я это сделал за Вас - из Вашего кода), который *воспроизводит* описываемую проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Как видите код работает

```js
let deleteTODO = document.querySelector('.delete');

deleteTODO.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(1);
})
```

```html
<div class="delete">КНОПКА</div>
```

Задавайте правильно вопросы, для вопроса предоставьте минимальное работающие демо отображающие вашу проблему.
Проблема может быть с CSS с js... Ваш пример предоставленный для того чтоб вам помогли отлично работает, проблем нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
let deleteTODO = document.querySelector('.delete');
```

Вернет первый элемент с совпадающим селектором. Если элементов много нужно использовать

```
let deleteTODOS = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');
```

или

```
let deleteTODOS =document.getElementsByClassName('.delete')
```

и по каждому проходится циклом или мапом